Improper integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\sec(x)-\tan(x)]\ dx$
I'm trying to solve this integral, so the first thing I did was to split this integral in two parts, then I got:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\sec(x)-\tan(x)]\ dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec(x)\ dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan(x)\ dx=$$
$$=[\ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x))]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0+[\ln(\cos(x))]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0$$
I'm getting the solution to be divergent from this data, but when I use Wolfram Alpha to check, it says that this converges to $\ln(2)$.
Could someone explain where I am making a mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$\log(\sec x +\tan x)+\log(\cos x)=\log(1+\sin x)$

hint: $$I=\int_0^{\pi \over 2}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}dx = \int_0^{\pi \over 2}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2 x} \cos x dx $$
Now try the substitution $u = \sin x$

@WW1 how are you giving hints? I didn't even understand the question. If you understand please edit the question :")

Following the hint given by @WW1,
Let $$I = \int_0^\frac \pi2(\sec x-\tan x)\mathrm dx $$
$$I = \int_0^\frac \pi2\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}\right)\mathrm dx $$
$$I = \int_0^\frac \pi2\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2x}\right)\cos x\;\mathrm dx $$
Now, put $$\sin x=t$$
then $$\cos x\;\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$$
The upper and the lower limits of the integral are $1$ and $0$ respectively.
So,
$$I = \int_0^1\left(\frac{1-t}{1-t^2}\right)\mathrm dt $$
$$I = \int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t} $$
$$I = \left.\ln(1+t)\right\rvert_0^1$$
$$I = \ln(2)-\ln(1) = \ln(2)$$

This does not explain where the OP made a mistake.

See the answer by Travis Wilse below, it explains why it can't be approached directly which is what OP did.

It can be approached directly, but you have to write it as a limit, not directly substitute for $x$ from the upper limit.

You should use the relation
$\ln(uv)=\ln(u)+\ln(v).$
Here $u=\sec(x)+\tan(x), v=\cos(x)$ leads to the product $uv$ remaining bounded and nonzero as $x\to\pi/2$. You are to figure out this product and retrieve Wolfram Alpha's (correct) result.

While the definite integral $$\int_0^\frac\pi2 (\sec x - \tan x) \,dx$$ converges, the integrals $$\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sec x \,dx \quad \textrm{and} \quad \int_0^\frac\pi2 \tan x \,dx$$ do not, so we cannot evaluate the original definite integral evaluating these latter integrals.

Alternatively,
$$\sec x - \tan x =\frac{1 - \sin x}{\cos x} = \tan \left(\frac x2 - \frac\pi4\right) ,$$ so

$$\int_0^\frac\pi2 (\sec x - \tan x) \,dx = \left. 2 \log \sec \left(\frac x2 - \frac\pi4\right)\right\vert_0^\frac\pi2 = \boxed{\log 2} . $$


You have proceeded correctly, but note that you have to plug in the values of $x$ from the limits as per the $2^{\text{nd}}$ part of the FTC in the form of a limit when the integral is improper and not directly substitute. Otherwise, you can end up with an indeterminate form when the definite integral actually converges.
Here, since the function $\sec x-\tan x$ has an essential discontinuity at $x=\frac{\pi}2$, hence by the definition of improper integrals,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sec x-\tan x\ dx$$
$$=\lim_{t\to\pi/2}\int_{0}^{t}\sec x-\tan x\ dx$$
$$=\lim_{t\to\pi/2}[\ln(\sec x+\tan x)-\ln(\sec x)]_0^{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to\pi/2}[\ln(1+\sin x)]_0^{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to\pi/2}\ln(1+\sin t)$$
$$=\boxed{\ln 2}$$
